# How to move currentlocation pin smoother animation when update location called

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am implementing MKMapView based application. In that I showed the current location with a pin. When my current location is changed the pin is blinking to the updated location. But my requirement is to stop blinking and make an animation or move the pin smoother with out blinking.

I tried in many ways but I didn't find a solution on this. I had the previous and current frames of the location pin. Is it possible to make this requirement with these values?

Answer (score 1):

you can use user current location by default. that will automatically animated. my code as below

```
  map=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
  map.delegate=self;
  map.zoomEnabled=YES;
  map.scrollEnabled=YES;
  map.showsUserLocation=YES;
  map.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
  map.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;
```